# Dropping column using tidyverse and base R - the difference

Tags: r, dplyr

While trying to fit a `randomForest` and to use `select` to choose/drop columns of data frame by name I ended up with a strange behaviour:

```
library(MASS)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(randomForest)

train = base::sample(1:nrow(Boston), nrow(Boston)/2)
glimpse(Boston)
p <- ncol(Boston) - 1
ps <- 1:p
map_dbl(ps, ~mean(randomForest(x = select(Boston[train,], -medv), 
                           y = select(Boston[train,], medv), 
                           xtest = select(Boston[-train,], -medv),
                           ytest = select(Boston[-train,], medv),
                           mtry = .x, ntree = 500)$test$mse))
```

This ended up with following error:

> Error in randomForest.default(x = select(Boston[train, ], -medv), y = select(Boston[train,  : 
>     length of response must be the same as predictors
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In randomForest.default(x = select(Boston[train, ], -medv), y = select(Boston[train,  :
>     The response has five or fewer unique values.  Are you sure you want to do regression?

However, when I defined x, y, xtest, ytest with base R the formula works:

```
map_dbl(ps, ~mean(randomForest(x = Boston[train, -14], 
                           y = Boston[train, 14], 
                           xtest = Boston[-train, -14],
                           ytest = Boston[train, 14],
                           mtry = .x, ntree = 500)$test$mse))
```

> [1] 119.9225 132.5212 136.7131 139.7398 142.9167 144.2151 145.0587 146.9056 148.7087 148.1903 150.3910
>   [12] 151.5579 151.2323

So I have checked if these two different ways of subsetting my dataset give the same results... and the do.

```
all(select(Boston[train,], -medv) == Boston[train, -14])
all(select(Boston[train,], medv) == Boston[train, 14])
all(select(Boston[-train,], -medv) == Boston[-train, -14])
all(select(Boston[-train,], medv) == Boston[-train, 14])
```

All of these results in `TRUE`. Why the first subsetting approach with use of `select` ends up with error in `randomForest` model then? What is the other way to drop the column using their name? (something like `Boston[,-"medv"]` which obviously doesn't work.

Comment: Make sure you are using the `select` function from the `dplyr` package, not from the `MASS` package.

Comment: Are you sure there is a variable called "train"? I run your code and I get the following error: Error in `[.data.frame`(Boston, train, -14) : object 'train' not found

Comment: @ScipioneSarlo, edited with `train` definition, @www Yes, I have checked it with `dpyr::select`

Answer (score 3):

The issue is with the y's in `randomForest`. They need to be vectors and not data.frames.

If you use `dplyr::select` it always returns a data.frame.

```
str(dplyr::select(Boston, medv)
'data.frame':   506 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ medv: num  24 21.6 34.7 33.4 36.2 28.7 22.9 27.1 16.5 18.9 ...
```

compared to selecting a single column via base R

```
str(Boston[, 14])
 num [1:506] 24 21.6 34.7 33.4 36.2 28.7 22.9 27.1 16.5 18.9 ...
```

To get the same result as dplyr when selecting 1 column, you need drop = FALSE in a data.frame single column select.

```
str(Boston[, 14, drop = FALSE])
'data.frame':   506 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ medv: num  24 21.6 34.7 33.4 36.2 28.7 22.9 27.1 16.5 18.9 ...
```

For getting your code correct you can use `as_vector` from `purrr` to force the data.frame containing `medv` into a vector.

```
map_dbl(ps, ~mean(randomForest(x = dplyr::select(Boston[train,], -medv), 
                               y = as_vector(dplyr::select(Boston[train,], medv)), 
                               xtest = dplyr::select(Boston[-train,], -medv),
                               ytest = as_vector(dplyr::select(Boston[-train,], medv)),
                               mtry = .x, ntree = 500)$test$mse)) 



[1] 22.36214 15.52031 13.24707 12.22685 12.32809 11.82220 11.91149 11.65336 12.05399 12.16599 12.63174 12.79196 12.41167
```

Answer (score 3):

Run the following code, we can see that the second and fourth lines are actually different.

```
identical(select(Boston[train,], -medv), Boston[train, -14])
# [1] TRUE
identical(select(Boston[train,], medv), Boston[train, 14])
# [1] FALSE
identical(select(Boston[-train,], -medv), Boston[-train, -14])
# [1] TRUE
identical(select(Boston[-train,], medv), Boston[-train, 14])
# [1] FALSE
```

The key is `select(Boston[train,], medv)` returns a data frame, but `Boston[train, 14]` returns a vector. It looks like we need to provide a vector to the `y` and `ytest` argument.

As a result, the following will work because `pull` from the [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr) package returns a vector.

```
map_dbl(ps, ~mean(randomForest(x = select(Boston[train,], -medv), 
                               y = pull(Boston[train,], medv), 
                               xtest = select(Boston[-train,], -medv),
                               ytest = pull(Boston[-train,], medv),
                               mtry = .x, ntree = 500)$test$mse))
```

We can also use `pluck` from the [purrr](/questions/tagged/purrr) package.

```
map_dbl(ps, ~mean(randomForest(x = select(Boston[train,], -medv), 
                               y = pluck(Boston[train,], "medv"), 
                               xtest = select(Boston[-train,], -medv),
                               ytest = pluck(Boston[-train,], "medv"),
                               mtry = .x, ntree = 500)$test$mse))
```

One final thing, I think for your second example, the `ytest` argument should be `Boston[-train, 14]`, you lack a minus sign.